# Create one handle from anchor point in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

In Illustrator, if you option/alt click and drag from an anchor point it creates two handles either side that you can create a curved point with. Is it possible to do the same but just a single handle on one side? I have tried to explain using the image attached. I could get the result I'm looking for other ways, but I always wondered if it could be done this way, as I feel it would be the easiest. Thanks. [image]

Comment: Are you looking to create a cusp point while using the pen tool, or after the path is already drawn?

Comment: @GeoffBall Thank you but agiopnl's answer worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presss Shift + C untill the arrow becomes an angle, then press the one handle you want to remove. The curve becomes a sharp edge instead.

Comment: Thank you! Assuming you can simply drag one handle out, that is the next best thing. Another question out of interest. You can also (with the pen tool selected) hold option/alt to turn it into the angle cursor. However it doesn't seem to do the same thing when you click a handle with it. What is the difference between this and shift+c (anchor point tool)?

Answer (score 0):

In My Experience holding down option/alt with the pen tool selected, though while showing the icon for the convert anchor point tool, only serves partially with the same function being able to remove both handles from an anchor point by clicking directly on the anchor point. However unlike when you click shift+C and actually switch to the convert anchor point tool, holding down option/alt with the pen key doesn't allow you to click on a single handle to remove it. it's likely just an over looked error or something. So if you want to remove both handles from an anchor point, temporarily accessing the convert anchor point tool by holding down option/alt with the pen tool selected will suffice. But if you just want to remove a single handle from an anchor point your going to have to switch over to the fully functional convert anchor point tool using shift+C.